# Double value issue - MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my Action method for a controller, I did some calculation as follows:

```
    double? total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        total = total + list[i] * quanttext[i];
    }
    ViewBag.finalpay = "Your total payment is $" + total;
```

My quanttext[i] is of double? type so I have to keep the total of the same type else I get an error.

When I pass the ViewBag.finalpay to the view and try to print it was follows:

```
@{
    string paymsg = ViewBag.finalpay;
 }
<p>
    @Html.Label(paymsg)
</p>
```

Label only prints the value correctly when my total is 25 or 29 like any integral value and it messes up when my total is 25.95 or something with decimal value.

Comment: Have you tried using total.ToString()?

Comment: Yes I did but still same problem.

Comment: What do you mean by it messes up?

Comment: Example if my total is 103.80
<p>
    <label for="Your_total_payment_is__103_8">8</label>
</p>
It prints only 8.

Comment: <p>
    <label for="Your_total_payment_is__54">Your total payment is $54</label>
</p>
This time it worked fine because my total is 54

Comment: If you change your `ViewBag.finalpay = "Your total payment is $" + total;` to `ViewBag.finalpay = "Your total payment is $" + total.ToString();`, does that help?

Comment: I did that too. I even did the following:
ViewBag.finalpay = ("Your total payment is $" + total).ToString();

Comment: How about `@Html.Label(paymsg, paymsg)`? According to MVC extensions documentation, the first item identifies what's being displayed, and the second item sets the actual text of the label. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions.label(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LabelExtensions.Label%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String%29

Comment: Yes it worked!! Thanks!
I also found that we can use @Html.Raw() but I didn't understand it's functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Using either of the following solved the problem.

```
<p>
    @Html.Label(paymsg,paymsg)
</p>

or 

<p>
    @Html.Raw(paymsg)
</p>
```